# Couchbase memory reservation configuration

Tags: couchbase

My couchbase installation (on BSD) reserves 15G RAM while the machine only has 4GB RAM available.

```
  PID USERNAME PRI NICE  SIZE   RES STATE     WAIT      TIME    CPU COMMAND
33106 root       2    0   15G  285M onproc/1  select   42:48  40.38% beam.smp
```

Couchbase runs fine for a month or so, but then the actual amount of used memore becomes bigger than memory available and as a consequence the machine starts swapping.

[image]

Where can I configure how much Couchbase shall reserve?

Comment: When you install Couchbase, you decide how much RAM to assign. It shouldn't allow you to assign more RAM than what's available. What version are you using and how are you installing it?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I'm not using the installer, I'm compiling it on BSD. I couldn't find the option where to define the max RAM. So when the installer defines max mem, where and what does it set/change?